# Where is the museum of socialist art in Sofia, Bulgaria?

Tags: bulgaria, museums, locate-this, sofia

I stumbled across [this article](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/44255439/ns/travel-destination_travel/t/bulgaria-opening-museum-socialist-art/) on a new socialist art museum in Sofia. It looks really interesting and since I'm in Sofia I'd like to visit.

[image]

But the article only lists "in a Sofia suburb", Google Maps doesn't find it, and my other searching isn't working for me yet. Maybe it would be easier to find by searching in Bulgarian or even Russian? Can anybody find its address for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently found only [this article](http://www.karolinkabulgaria.com/2011/08/27/a-new-museum-in-sofia-socialist-art/) with "maybe" address:
**Lachezar Stanchev Street in the Izgrev borough**
And from comments found news about that opening date is **September, 16**.

[This official news](http://sofiaecho.com/2011/08/26/1145333_national-art-gallery-in-sofia-to-close-for-four-months) also says that this address is right:

> Some of the National Art Gallery’s works are to go on travelling exhibitions, while some will go on temporary loan to the new Museum of Socialist Art, on Lachezar Stanchev Street in the Izgrev borough, near the Sofia office of the traffic police.

And [this news](http://www.novinite.com/view_news.php?id=129906) finally get the right address:

> [7 Lachezar Stanchev Str](http://g.co/maps/rqgk2) (ул. Лъчезар Станчев 7)

(Google map, wrong street title, but [from here](http://www.training.is-bg.net/maps/maps.html) location is right)

Comment: Amazed by your skillz!

Comment: do you see the **160 street**?

Comment: For somethat reason Google writes there a numbers instead of real street names. See my second link - there is a map of that district with Lachezar Stanchev street on it

Comment: OK so Google Maps sometimes accepts Ul. Lachezar Stanchev as an address, and it can find it. But it does not show its name. It makes it look as if it is Ul. 165 but that is the street curving around to the north of it. openstreetmap.org doesn't have the street at all. Bing Maps shows Lachezar Stanchev at maximum zoom on the street which really is Ul. 165!

Comment: @hippietrail This is why I prefer second map - it is with notes how to get on that street.

Comment: Aha street name problem solved! [A page on **Карта София**](http://www.kartasofia.com/%D1%83%D0%BB-%D0%BB%D1%8A%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2-karta42252.html) specifically says "Лъчезар Станчев е новото име на улици 170, 165 и 172" (Lachezar Stanchev is the new name of 170, 165, and 172 Streets).