# Does Georgia (the country) have a museum or sculpture park of Soviet/Communist/Socialist art?

Tags: georgia-country, museums, landmarks

In Budapest, Hungary they have **[Memento Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_Park)**. As covered in one of my previous questions, there is the **[Museum of Socialist Art](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/where-is-the-museum-of-socialist-art-in-sofia-bulgaria)** in Sofia, Bulgaria. I recall reading that some other former communist countries in the area also have such museums.

But does Georgia have any equivalent? I'm about to leave the country after spending six months there and can't recall hearing about one, though I've seen some impressive and/or outlandish monuments, memorials, statues, mosaics, etc. about the country.

In light of the fact that Georgia [is still removing and/or destroying some monuments of this type](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/georgia/8549052/Georgia-passes-law-to-destroy-Soviet-era-monuments-and-street-names.html) now, over 20 years after the fall of communism, do they also have a place which displays such relics?

(Yes I'm aware of the **[Stalin Museum in Gori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin_Museum,_Gori)**. While it does have the statue of Stalin that was still in front of the local parliament building until a couple of years ago, it's certainly not the same thing.)

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, there's a monument to Lenin with a sculpture (looks pretty interesting) in Tblisi. No full on park though.

[image]

Comment: No no this is so totally gone now you wouldn't recognize it if I put a photo of the same area now up here. I have found a few images of both Stalin and Lenin about the places but not so conspicuous.

Comment: wow, how things change :(

Comment: I do really love the huge old monuments from the communist era. Georgia has quite a few but the most amazing are in Bulgaria and the former Yugoslavia. Rose Revolutions Square is so run down and ugly right now that nobody is posting photos from a similar angle, just of the Radisson Blu hotel or the giant bicycle public sculpture. But here's some photos of what they're planning to develop it into: [\[1\]](http://www.s333.org/upload/prjImages/resized.568x376/RoseRevolutionSquare/s333-1167-4L.jpg), [\[2\]](http://s50.radikal.ru/i128/0905/03/822ed2586392.jpg).

Comment: And here's what it looked like after Lenin was removed but before the concrete arches were removed: [\[1\]](http://www.travel-images.com/georgia40.jpg).